# Altcoin does not create .altcoin folder and debug.log

Tags: altcoin, logging

I changed the source code of bitcoin and I ran it. However, it gives the following error:

```
chainparams.cpp:140: CMainParams::CMainParams(): Assertion `hashGenesisBlock == uint256("0xxx")' failed.
```

Aborted (core dumped)

It also does not create .altcoin folder in home folder, so I cannot see debug.log. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

The latest bitcoin source doesn't output any debug log in chainparams.cpp. 
You can,

1. Use [GenesisH0](https://github.com/lhartikk/GenesisH0) to find your Genesis block hash.
2. make && sudo make install
3. Run it again, then you will see debug.log within your bitcoin folder